# Undefined is not a function error with "defined" argument

Tags: javascript, function, evaluation

So this is a part of a simple JavaScript code to handle xmlhttprequest. The part that is generating the error is at the bottom (else if):

```
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (httpReq.status == 200) {
                var strRes = httpReq.responseText;
                if(xmlOrig) strRes = (new $Xml(strRes, true)).conteudo(xmlOrig);
                if(elemDest) $id(elemDest).innerHTML = strRes;
                if(func) {
                    var dadosArray = new Array(4, strRes, httpReq, 'OK', 'Concluído com sucesso.');
                    window[func](dadosArray);
                }
            } else {
                if(elemDest) elemDest.innerHTML = 'Erro: '+httpReq.status+' | '+httpReq.statusText;
                if(func) {
                    var dadosArray = new Array(4, false, httpReq, 'erro', 'Erro, conteúdo não carregado!');
                    window[func](dadosArray);
                }
            }
        } else if(func){
            console.log("func? "+typeof(func));
            var dadosArray = new Array(httpReq.readyState);
            window[func](dadosArray);  // <-- HERE IS THE ERROR!
        }
    }
```

However, the console.log return the "func" argument as a function, so where is the error?

The Safari console:

func? function
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'windowfunc')

Comment: Where do you define what the variable `func` is?  You're not passing it in or defining it anywhere?

Comment: I defined a testing function in the root. First, I though it was an error inside the function, but the testing function go nothing to do (as a test). I think it can be an error that Safari can't precise where.

Comment: I found it: func must be a String, so I can't define func = Function, but func = "NameOfTheFunction".

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `func` is on the window? You are checking for `func`, which could be inside any scope, and thne you can calling `window.func()`.

Comment: Since typeof(func) is returning "function", I assume the function is correctly defined, and I defined it in the root.

Comment: The answer: func must be a String, so I can't define func = Function, but func = "NameOfTheFunction".

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to do `window["func"]` instead of `window[func]`.

The latter expression is equivalent to `window["function(someParam) { ... }"]` (i.e., a whatever the content of `func` actually is). `window` probably does not have a property whose name is the entire stringified text content of `func`.

Comment: The function is not called "func". I'm using func = "doNothing" as a test, and function = doNothing(d){ } is defined in the root.

Comment: I found it. As long your idea is not the answer, it give me a different idea: func must be a String, so I can't define func = Function, but func = "NameOfTheFunction".

Comment: @GustavoPinent The name of the variable that holds the function is called `func`, and you identify that variable by name in bracket syntax by the string `"func"`. To generalize the two cases: `window["someString"]` refers to the global variable `someString`, while `window[someVar]` refers to a global variable whose name is *the contents of* `someVar`. If `someVar` is set to `"foo"`, then `window[someVar]` refers to the global `foo`.

Comment: Ok, but in this case, I wish to point a function to receive the responses, so window[func] will do the job (I must chose). The problem is that if func exists but doesn't has a string with the name of the function, Safari returns a generic "undefined" error. IMO Safari should return the appropriate error message, related to an argument that can't be evaluated in this context.